# Machine learning kmeans model in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to Machine learning. Just started with new project for a POC.

I have my dataset for model as a csv file in the below format.

My goal is to deduct the anomaly for any src/destination when there is a spike in in/out respectively.

```
timestamp src destination in  out  type
 00       p1    p2        2    3    abc
 00       p2    p3        1    4    abc
 00       p3    pn        3    5    abc
 05       p1    pn        4    3    abc
 05       p2    p1        2    2    abc
 10       p1    p3       91    6    abc <- src anomaly deduction
 10       px    py       30   92    abc <- dest anomay deduction
```

Here src maps to in. destination maps to out value.

I want to prepare a Kmean model for each src / destinaton with in and out in Spark using pyspark. I have no idea on what to do? How to prepare a model. Can you give me some pointer on this?

Thanks.